# Best way to copy Hive data from HDFS to another machine?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, fuse

Source: `/mnt/fuse/project/hive` (This is hive data on HDFS mounted using fuse)

Destination: `host:/fs/dir` (/fs/dir is again a network mounted storage and I do not have direct access to "host")

I did `rsync -avz -P -e ssh /mnt/fuse/project/hive user@host:/fs/dir` and this is very slow. I aborted the process and tried to kill rsync but could not do so, tried both kill -15 and kill -9.

Wondering if there is a better way to copy the data?

Comment: did you try distcp? The command line could be something like `hadoop distcp hdfs:///path/to/hivedata fs:///user@host:/fs/dir`

Comment: I think distcp is used to copy data in between clusters.

Comment: oh, it could be used with multiple schemes, i.e. hdfs, http, ftp, file..., i used it for cp files from HDFS to local file system with file:///, but i didn't try your case, that's the reason i suggested you to have a try

Comment: I have tried it and it throws me an exception "fs: scheme not found"